# Retrieving raw value from email field with mixed Chinese and Latin characters

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8, field, multilingual

Basically I'm trying to read raw field values, but cannot in some cases as shown below.

Consider a simple email form field:

```
<input type="email" name="username" id="username" />
```

When I input regular email, Javascript can read the value as expected. When I input all Chinese character, Javascript also can read the value as expected.
However when I mix latin and Chinese characters, Javascript seems to convert to some sort of code character set.

**Test examples:**

`test@test.com       //returns test@test.com
暮捕徹@暮捕徹.暮捕徹    //returns 暮捕徹@暮捕徹.暮捕徹
test@暮捕徹.com       //returns test@xn--r5t43fptd.com
test@test.暮捕徹      //returns test@test.xn--r5t43fptd`

**Test code:**

```js
function login(){
 var username=document.querySelector('#username').value;
  var resultDiv=document.createElement('DIV');
  resultDiv.innerText = username;
 document.querySelector('body').appendChild(resultDiv);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="javascript: return false;">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input type="email" name="username" id="username" />
  <button onclick="login();">
    Login
  </button>
</form>
```

**Things I've Tried:**

- I have set in `<head>`:
  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`
- I had set utf-8 in form field:
  `<input type="email" name="username" id="username" accept-charset="utf-8" />`

Comment: Based on Gibolt's answer, I ended up including punycode as part of the input data requirements, and doing my data handling based on this converted string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called Punycode. It converts unicode to latin characters so any device can enter them. You can check out [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184802/are-chinese-characters-allowed-entered-in-urls) to get a more extensive description.

For a solution, please checkout [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183485/converting-punycode-with-dash-character-to-unicode) and see if it suits your needs. Good luck!